# Style parameter can't be identified

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm actually new to flutter and dart and I'm facing a problem for a couple of hours. I am using VS code and the code is from a tutorial (The code is working for the Tutor just fine...).
The Problem is that the style Parameter as seen in the following picture can't be identified.

Picture of code

[image: Picture of code]

Picture of Problem

[image: Picture of Problem]

I've already read a view other posts of stackoverflow, but I dont get it. My Path variables should be all right and I've checked all extensions and everything works right.
Also my Dart Sdk path in VScode is set to the right location:

C:\Users\Steffen Hain\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

Appreciate your help!

Comment: you gotta read about what are brackets and braces in oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you closed the text widget before the style just remove the comma and the bracket shown in the image and put it where the blue arrow is:

[image]

hope it helped